# What are the visa requirements for an Iranian transiting in Amsterdam, The Netherlands?

Tags: transit-visas, netherlands, iranian-citizens

I have an Iranian passport and my round trip flight from San Francisco (SFO) to Istanbul (IST) has a stop in Amsterdam, The Netherlands for eight hours.

1. Do I need a transit visa?
2. How is the application process and how long it generally takes to get a transit visa?
3. Do I need to get a separate transit visa for the return flight?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the Dutch [embassy](http://iran.nlembassy.org/services/consular-affairs/visa/information-sheet-visa-applications-for-airport-transit-visa.html) in Iran, **you don't need a transit visa**. (Flying out of SFO, I'm assuming you have at least a US tourist visa or a green card)

> **Airport transit visa:**
>
> Besides the visa mentioned above Iranian passport holders should apply
>   for an airport transit visa if they travel via The Netherlands to a
>   country outside the Schengen area.
>
> **Some persons are exempted:**
>
> - Holders of a valid Schengen visa
> - Holder of valid permit of stay of a
>     Country member of the European Union
> - Holders of a valid permit of stay issued by Andorra, Canada, Japan, San Marino or the United States
> - Holders diplomatic passports

Comment: Thank you for your response :) Very helpful and to the point!